# Ensure LINQ to SQL Entities Delete On Submit

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

What is the best way to mark some entities DeleteOnSubmit(). Is there a way to check and say to the context that this is for deletion?

Example: I have an Entity which reference an EntitySet<> and i delete from the EntitySet<> 4 of the 8 entities. When submitting changes i want to say DeleteOnSubmit() on those 4! This scenario should play on a single EntityRef<> too.

Of course DataContext lives in another layer so...grabbing, changing, sending back is the job.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty hard to answer based on the description of your architecture.  Just because you're using a layered approach doesn't mean that you can't call `DeleteOnSubmit`... you'd just call your own method that wraps that I presume.

Unless, of course, you're instantiating your DataContext object in the update routine.  in this case you'd have to do something else.  Your data layer could expose a method like `MarkForDelete()` which just adds the entity to a collection, then expose a separate `SubmitChanges()` that iterates over the collected items for deletion, attaches them to the datacontext and then does the actual `DeleteAllOnSubmit()` call.

That said I've never really bothered with the whole entity serialization/deserialization/reattach thing as it seems [fraught with peril](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/156631.aspx).  I usually just collect the primary keys in a list, select out the entities and re-delete them.  It's no more work, really.

Comment: I used this approach yesterday...thanx for reply

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at DeleteAllOnSubmit(). You pass this method a list of entities to be deleted.

Comment: I cant pass all my EntitySet for deletion, i will lose them all, maybe you mean of keeping track the entities Id in another List<> and use them to DeleteOnSubmit() those entities?